# forked ember npm run build fails

Tags: ember.js

I cannot seem to build ember.js on my system (mac osx Yosemite node v0.11.14 npm 2.0.0
. `npm install` works but `npm run build` produces the following output:

```
    Cannot find module './build/Release/shell'
    Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/shell'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/stockn/ember.js/node_modules/ember-cli-yuidoc/node_modules/execSync/index.js:30:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/stockn/ember.js/node_modules/ember-cli-yuidoc/lib/commands/yuidoc.js:3:19)
```

Comment: On my other back I have no problems! weird! wonder whats different.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the version of node was the problem. I installed node version manager https://github.com/creationix/nvm then ran
`nvm install 0.10.26`
now `npm run build` runs successfully.